# Set default option in select-element using php

Tags: php, html, select, default

I'm looking for a simple way to dynamically change the default item in a select-element without adding a ton of code into every option-element.
This is an example of a select-element that allows you to select a month and it always sets the current month as the default item:

```
    <select name="month">
        <option <?php echo ((date("n")==1)?'selected="selected"':'')?> value="1">Januar</option>
        <option <?php echo ((date("n")==2)?'selected="selected"':'')?> value="2">Februar</option>
        <option <?php echo ((date("n")==3)?'selected="selected"':'')?> value="3">M&auml;rz</option>
        <option <?php echo ((date("n")==4)?'selected="selected"':'')?> value="4">April</option>
        <option <?php echo ((date("n")==5)?'selected="selected"':'')?> value="5">Mai</option>
        <option <?php echo ((date("n")==6)?'selected="selected"':'')?> value="6">Juni</option>
        <option <?php echo ((date("n")==7)?'selected="selected"':'')?> value="7">Juli</option>
        <option <?php echo ((date("n")==8)?'selected="selected"':'')?> value="8">August</option>
        <option <?php echo ((date("n")==9)?'selected="selected"':'')?> value="9">September</option>
        <option <?php echo ((date("n")==10)?'selected="selected"':'')?> value="10">Oktober</option>
        <option <?php echo ((date("n")==11)?'selected="selected"':'')?> value="11">November</option>
        <option <?php echo ((date("n")==12)?'selected="selected"':'')?> value="12">Dezember</option>
      </select>
```

As you can see, there is just way too much code in it.

I'm wondering if anyone of you has a better idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
<?php
$months = [
    1=>'January',
    2=>'february',
    3=>'march'
    ....//etc
];
?>

<select name="month">
    <?php foreach($months as $key=>$month):?>
        <option <?= ((date("n")==$key)?'selected="selected"':'')?> value="<?= $key;?>"><?= $month;?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of months and then check it like that.

```
<?php
 $months = array(
  array(
    "monthNumber" => 1,
    "name" => "January"
  ),
  array(
    "monthNumber" => 2,
    "name" => "Feb"
  ),
  array(
    "monthNumber" => 3,
    "name" => "March"
  )
);
?>

<select name="month">
 <?php
  foreach ($months as $month) {
   echo "<option " . ((date("n") == $month['monthNumber']) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''). ">".$month['name']."</option>";
  }
 ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use foreach loop

```
    <?php
    $months=array('1'=>'January','2'=>'Febuary','3'=>'March',4=>'April','5'=>'May','6'=>'June','7'=>'July','8'=>'August','9'=>'September',10=>'October','11'=>'November','12'=>'December');
    ?>
    <select name='month'>
    <?php foreach($months as $num=>$month) {?>
     <option <?php echo ((date("n")==$num)?'selected="selected"':'')?>value="<?php echo $num;?>"><?php echo $month; ?>
    </option> 
   </select>
```

It may be helpful..